What is SIGMA_WRITE into Snowlake Queries History?
please tell me what SIGMA_WRITE is in Snowlake Queries History.
For example:
MERGE INTO SIGMA.SIGMA_WRITE.SIGDS_WAL_f0a628d8_f904_4c20_bdd0_bcb8e1d2d607 target USING ((SELECT ? as DS_ID, ? as EDIT_ID, ? as USER_ID, ? as EDIT_NUM, ? as PROTOCOL_VERSION, ? as EDIT, ? as METADATA, ? as TIMESTAMP)) source ON target.DS_ID = source.DS_ID AND target.EDIT_ID = source.EDIT_ID WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (source.DS_ID, source.EDIT_ID, source.USER_ID, source.EDIT_NUM, source.PROTOCOL_VERSION, source.EDIT, source.METADATA, source.TIMESTAMP)

I'm trying to investigate the most costly groups of queries. I found that queries using SIGMA_WRITE are the most expensive, but I don't know what the queries are. We use Sigma as a BI tool.

From the merge script it look's like SIGMA_WRITE  is your schema name.
